# VueJS Application should call PHP backend on port 80 when using AJAX in a Docker application

Tags: php, docker, vue.js

I have a simple VueJS app that I am running in a docker container.
When I am making AJAX requests to my PHP backend, I am specifying the port I am using.
But I want it to work on port 80 and I do not know how to do that.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  todo-app:
    build: /app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - php-backend
    #volumes:
      #- /node_modules
      #- ./:/app
      #- /php
      #- /node_modules

  php-backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    #volumes:
      #- /php:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=todo
      - DB_USERNAME=todo-app-user
      - DB_PASSWORD=default

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=todo
      - MYSQL_USER=todo-app-user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=default
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=default
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

My Dockerfile in PHP:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

COPY . /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "apache2-foreground" ]
```

My Dockerfile in App:

```
FROM node:19.7-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]
```

When I open my Vue App in the browser it returns a 404 not found in the AJAX requests.

Comment: You cant have both the vue app and the php backend on the same port, your need to place a proxy (nginx, apache mod_proxy, caddy, etc) in front of both which rewrites routes say /api goes to your backend, everything else into the vue app, or simpler make the API in nodejs, combine into nuxt or something with SSR or static build your app and put it in the apache container

Answer (score 0):

Container in docker see each other with the container-names as domainname and the internal ports. Request-URL 'php-backend:80' should do the trick.

Edit: Just realized the ajax-request is from your local browser, not from within the todo-app-container, the answer would not help. But then I do not see the problem. The request to 'localhost:8080' should go to the php-backend